# Filter for Unanswered when clicking on Tags from the /Unanswered page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

Here's the simple version of my request:

[image]

The first thing I usually do when coming to SO is click on the Unanswered link, then scroll through the Unanswered Tags to find my favorite tags and click on them. There's two problems with this:

- The Unanswered Tag list is fairly long, and its time consuming to search through the list and find my favorite tags
- Not all my Favorite Tags are in the list, so I have to  manually type the URL to get a list of Unanswered questions in some of my favorite tags (which translates to me not checking new questions in that list very often because I'm lazy)

Below that list is a perfectly good list of my Favorite Tags containing all the tags I'm interested in, however clicking on the tag takes me to a complete list of questions in that tag, not to just the Unanswered questions.

Can you make it so clicking on a Tag from the `/Unanswered` page takes you to `/Unanswered/Tagged/Tag` instead of `/Questions/Tagged/Tag`?

I'd also settle for this behavior on just the Favorite tag list :)

Comment: Why has this not been done already? +100 if I could, I am definitely lazy as well and this would make SO time much more productive.

Comment: Wow would this ever be useful.

Comment: Funny, was nailbiting over this just half an hour ago, and now I run into this post hehe.

Comment: Discussing this now.

Comment: Thanks @JarrodDixon. Also, by any chance did you refund my bounty? Or is it a new feature that bounties get refunded to their owners when they don't get an answer? :)

Comment: Yes, I refunded it, since I wasn't going to answer definitively about it yet.  No need to waste those unicorn bucks needlessly!

Comment: @JarrodDixon Thank you, I'm just happy to know it's on the dev's team radar now, even if it does end up being something not implemented or pushed far down the list of things-to-do-someday :)

Comment: @JarrodDixon the discussion minutes please :)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is being built out now, minus moving "Favorite Tags" above "Unanswered Tags".

However, I agree with that movement; we're discussing making your "Favorite Tags" always be above any "Related Tags" on pages they both appear.

Comment: I noticed the list of "Related Tags" is much shorter too, thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, the /unanswered pages weren't reusing the related tags code that /questions and /questions/tagged use, so that small refactor allowed the "show more" collapsing, too.