# Easily finding unanswered->no answer questions with tags I have as favorite

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, unanswered-questions

Right now I can do:

- Unanswered->my tags -- This will give me questions that *have* answers, but no accepted answers for my tags. Downside: a lot of questions have perfectly valid answers but an answer has not yet been accepted (maybe never will) and therefor I'm wasting my time.
- Search for [tag] and selecting unanswered -- this will give me questions with no answers at all for the given search tag. Downside: I have to copy/paste or write all my tags every time I want to search.

Also, in the above, the definition of "unanswered" isn't the same: in the first it means no accepted answer and in the second it means no answers at all.

I want to easily be able to search for questions with no answer at all that matches my favorite tags. This would allow me to avoid the questions with perfectly valid answers, and at the same time save me time from writing all my tags again and again to search.

Comment: You mean like this? [Filter for Unanswered when clicking on Tags from the /Unanswered page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169500/158605)

Comment: I'd say it's a bit related. We both want to find posts with no accepted answers and no answers at all for our favorite tags. That guy wants to simply be able to click on his favorite tags to see the lists for each tag seperately -- I want to have a list of unanswered+noanswer questions that matches any of my favorite tags.

Comment: I am accepting this. But now, using second methode, is much good.