# Current tag filter does not get saved when clicking on a Tag

Tags: bug, status-norepro, new-nav, navigation

I opened [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256861/158605) about the same issue after the [first iteration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256814/158605) of the New Navigation, and it was fixed.

With the [second iteration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261307/158605) of the New Navigation, this problem is back and it is driving me crazy.

Can someone please fix it?

If I have the [needs answers] tab selected, and I click on a tag to refine my results further by that tag, it should not take me back to the [new] tab.

---

<sub>Also, this may be a good example of a question to use for [this discussion on how to handle obsolete questions...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/158605) :)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

In the previous iterations we automatically saved the tab you visited last as your home tab. This was kind of intrusive since clicking on a link somebody shared could screw up your defaults. In the current iteration you have to set it up explicitly via the home tab picker:

[image: home tab picker]

So if you spend most of your time looking for unanswered questions set the needs answer tab as your home tab.

Furthermore, refining a filter was never the first click on a tag. It has always been a click on a tag in the related tags list. Clicking any other tag (outside the related tags sidebar) takes you to that tags home page (which is on your home tab):

[image: go home vs refine]

Comment: As someone who does not want to change my default home tab, can I get this updated to maintain the current "tab" page when I click on a tag in one of the sidebar lists? This is the [current navigation behavior](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169500/158605), and it was something that was also [fixed in the first iteration of the new navigation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259276/158605). I greatly miss this, as I often use the ability to click on a tab to further refine what I am looking at, whether that is unanswered, bounties, highly voted Qs, etc.